# How does the C compiler treat -10u?

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.>

int main() {
    signed x;
    unsigned y;

    x = 10 +- 10u + 10u +- 10;
    y = x;
    if(x==y)
        printf("%d %d",x,y);
    else if(x!=y)
        printf("%u  %u",x,y);
    return 0;
}
```

I can't understand the flow of the above program. Please explain how the compiler treats `-10u` as default. From my understanding `10u` is unsigned, but in this program it automatically converted it into -10.

http://www.cquestions.com/2012/02/data-type-questions-in-c.html, question no. 3.

Comment: The printf should be `printf("%d %u", x, y);` regardless of the values - the types must match the specifiers.

Comment: Your `printf` functions invoke undefined behaviour, anything can happen, any result is valid, including the program formatting your harddrive.

Answer (score 6):

`-10u` is a "unary minus" operator applied to a constant `10u` of type `unsigned int`. The result is value of `-10` represented in the domain of `unsigned int` type. According to the rules of unsigned arithmetic, the final result will be equal to `UINT_MAX + 1 - 10` and will have type `unsigned int`.

Answer (score 2):

> in this program it automatically converted into -10

It does not convert to -10, it converts to a large positive number that *behaves* like -10 when you perform an addition.

C standard says:

> A computation involving unsigned operands can never overflow, because a result that cannot be represented by the resulting unsigned integer type is reduced modulo the number that is one greater than the largest value that can be represented by the resulting type

A consequence of this behavior is that when you add `10` to `- 10u`, the result is "one greater than the largest value that can be represented by the resulting type", so it gets truncated to zero. This is exactly the behavior that you get when adding `+10` and `-10` using a signed type.

Perhaps this behavior is easier to understand with decimals. Suppose you have a system that can represent numbers 0..99, with 100 wrapping back to zero. Then 10 would remain 10, while -10 would become 99+1-10=90. Now when you add 10 and 90, you get 100, which gets truncated to zero.

Comment: sorry dasblinkenlight. i cannot understand please explain clearly

Comment: @MuniyasamyV Sorry, I can hardly get clearer than that: the last paragraph is written at the level of a ten-years old middle school student.